# how to use Jquery Dialog Along with fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, dialog, popup, fullcalendar, conflict

when i use jQuery dialog along with fullcalendar, my js files conflicts .
how to solve this isuse?

this is what i am trying to do.

```
    $(function () {

        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 1000
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "explode",
                duration: 1000
            }
        });

        $("#opener").click(function () {

            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        });
    });






    $(document).ready(function () {
        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            aspectRatio: 2,

            eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

                alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);

               **// on this event click i want pop-up** 
            },


            dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view)
            {


                $(this).css('background-color', 'cyan');

            },
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next,today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            editable: true,
            events: [

                {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, 1)
                },
                {
                    title: 'Long Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d - 2)
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d - 3, 16, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d + 4, 16, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Lunch',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Birthday Party',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Click for Google',
                    start: new Date(y, m, 28),
                    end: new Date(y, m, 29),
                    url: 'http://google.com/'
                }
            ]
        });

    });
```

on event click of calendar i want a pop up showing the event title.
help is much appreciated as soon as possible.

Comment: What do you mean your js files conflict?

Comment: Take a look at http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/. They have a note using another plugin to do what you want.

Comment: if i use a js file for dialog box..my full calendar disappers..thats why i use "confilt " term

Comment: Did you take a look at eventRender? You should be adding the dialog to the element in eventRender.